# How do I get value of select option for current row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have dynamic field to generate select option & text input.

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><select name="itemType[]" id="itemType_'+i+'" class="form-control input-sm"><option value="AAA">AAA</option><option value="BBB">BBB</option></select></td>';
    .....
    .....
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
    type = $(this).data('type');
    if(type =='itemName' )autoTypeNo=0;
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'ajax',
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    search : request.term,
                    type : type,
                    select : $("#itemType_"+i).val()
                }
                success: function( data ) {}
            ..
```

Why the `$("#itemType_"+i).val()` return an empty value? I have missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the current `select` will have a `id` say `itemType_7` but the value of `i` will be `8` as you are incrementing it after creating the `select`.

So the fetch the value of latest `select` you have created, you should do

`$("#itemType_"+(i-1)).val()`